# Problems adding external library to Android Studio 0.3.6

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Today I started working with Android Studio 0.3.6 and I need to export a library to my project. I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588064/how-do-i-add-a-library-project-to-the-android-studio) and I tried the different ways to add an external library but when I try to import it does not find the library namespaces.

Comment: do read your question first,is it understandable for other or not also always add 4 or 5 tags to your questions so  that it can attract the users to answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you read my answer on [Adding external library in Android studio 0.3.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241765/adding-external-library-in-android-studio-0-3-6/20242441#20242441) it should give you the most up-to-date information for 0.3.6.

Sorry, I know it's confusing, and there's conflicting information out there. That's because the right functionality is slowly rolling out in Android Studio, and some of the functionality that was there didn't do the right thing, meaning developers had to come up with complex workarounds. Depending on what version of Android Studio was out at the time various Stack Overflow questions were asked, you may get different advice that no longer applies.

Comment: Your answer does link to a workaround. Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ IDEA which works like a charm without all thise issues of Android Studio. I recommend using the original IDE instead of a broken fork in ALPHA stage.

Answer (score -2):

Currently most features of Android Studio seems to be broken. I had the same issue and came to a real [final solution: avoid Android Studio and use the origin IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20241765/adding-external-library-in-android-studio-0-3-6/20242441#20242441).